# Does Sony provide Camera Emulator for testing Camera Remote API

Tags: camera, sony

Does Sony provide Camera Emulator for testing apps made with Camera Remote API https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/get-started/ 
Or
Do i need to use actual Camera device in order to test apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no emulator available, so you will need to test on a hardware device.